# Go Ranged Loop Scope and Indirect Function

Tags: loops, go, scope

Can someone help enlighten me with the "why" aspect of the following surprise I had with golang loop scoping and temporary functions?  Following is an excerpt reduction from some more-complex code:

```
package main

import ( "fmt" )

type Caller struct {
    call func()
}

func printer(val int) {
    fmt.Printf("the value is %v\n", val)
}

func main () {
    values := []int{1,2,3}

    var callers []Caller
    for _,val := range values {
        call := func() { printer(val) }
        callers = append(callers, Caller{call})
    }

    for _, caller := range callers {
        caller.call()
    }
}
```

which produces the (to me) surprising outcome:

```
the value is 3
the value is 3
the value is 3
```

If I alter that code by changing the range values loop body to this:

```
        theVal := val
        call := func() { printer(theVal) }
        callers = append(callers, Caller{call})
```

then we get the originally hoped-for result:

```
the value is 1
the value is 2
the value is 3
```

Fundamentally, one works and the other doesn't - I'm clear on that and can try to just memorize the idiom.  I'm hoping for more understanding, perhaps a little life lesson in golang.  What is it about scoping rules and deferred execution that means the loop variable maintains the final valid value and is submitted into every one of the temporary functions built during the loop?  Why isn't the value "val" dropped into the dynamically-built func "call"?  I suspect that I am confused about something fundamental.  Even seeing a working version, I am not certain I will be able to avoid a trap like this in the future.  If you have advice for "why" the iterated value acts like that, I'd love to hear it (and thank you in advance).

Comment: See the FAQ on gelang.org. Loop have just one variable, only the value changes.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I will memorize it.  :)  For any audience, at this link: https://golang.org/doc/faq "One might mistakenly expect to see a, b, c as the output. What you'll probably see instead is c, c, c. This is because each iteration of the loop uses the same instance of the variable v, so each closure shares that single variable."

Comment: @Volker edit gelang.org to golang.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you as well. Here's the link from the [FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Caller struct {
    call func()
}

func printer(val int) {
    fmt.Printf("the value is %v\n", val)
}

func main() {
    values := []int{1, 2, 3}

    var callers []Caller
    for _, val := range values {
        var call func()
        func(v int) {
            call = func() {
                printer(v)
            }
        }(val)
        callers = append(callers, Caller{call})
    }
    for _, caller := range callers {
        caller.call()
    }
}
```

An alternate method would be to bind the current value of val to each closure as it is launched, you can store it in a new variable and then use it (the method you have done to solve it).

Comment: Thank you for that, and for the direct link.

Comment: @Bill Could you mark it as accepted so that community knows that this question is solved?

Comment: Done, sorry for that.  What's still interesting to me about this is that this applies to closures; the FAQ describes concurrency, but clearly you don't have to be running a concurrent program to encounter this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a `val := val` inside your loop would be enough to make it work (see [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/bhqHMn9ZmEB))

As you [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63539041/go-ranged-loop-scope-and-indirect-function#comment112355981_63539041):

> This is because each iteration of the loop uses the same instance of the variable `v`, so each closure shares that single variable.

But... That might change.
The discussion "[redefining for loop variable semantics](https://github.com/golang/go/discussions/56010)" is precisely about that:

> We have talked for a long time about redefining these semantics, to make loop variables **per-iteration** instead of per-loop.
>
> That is, the change would effectively be to add an implicit "`x := x`" at the start of every loop body for each iteration variable `x`, just like people do manually today.
> Making this change would remove the bugs from the programs above.

Possibly for Go 1.30, with lots of warning in the meantime)

> To make the breakage completely user controlled, the way the rollout would work is to change the semantics based on the go line in each package’s `go.mod` file, the same line we already use for enabling language features (you can only use generics in packages whose go.mod says “go 1.18” or later).
>
> Just this once, we would use the line for changing semantics instead of for adding a feature or removing a feature.
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/104030/193599987-19d8f564-cb40-488e-beaa-5093a4823ee0.png]

This is still actively discussed though.